# Compare users out of an array with /etc/shadow file

Tags: linux, shell-script

I want to check for all users who do not have a password set.

For example, a user with the following entry in `/etc/passwd`

```
test01::15164: ...*
```

has no password set. I would like to list all such users.

```
declare -a liste=(test 01 test02)
for a in `echo ${liste[@]}`
do
    for b in `cat /etc/shadow`
    do
        if [[ "$a" == "$b" ]]
        then
            echo $a
        fi
    done
done
```

The code doesn't give any output or errors

**Solution**

The entry in the shadow file witout a password are usertest01 & tecusertest01

```
declare -a liste=(usertest01 usertest 02 tecusertest01 tecusertest02)

for sdw in `awk -F: '$2 == ""' /etc/shadow`

        do

                user=`echo "$sdw" | awk -F: '{print $1}'`

                echo "$user"

                echo  "${liste[@]}" | grep "$user" > /dev/null

                if [ $? -eq 0 ]
                        then

                                echo "Human user"

                                echo "$user"  | passwd "$user" --stdin

                        else

                                echo "Technical User"

                fi

        done
```

**Output**

```
usertest01
Human user
usertest01
Changing password for user usertest01.
passwd: all authentication tokens updated successfully.
tecusertest01
Technical User
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can simply check using :

Note:- Run following command using `sudo`, because `/etc/shadow` has only read access to root user & group.

```
awk -F: '$2 == ""' /etc/shadow
```

OR

```
awk -F: 'length($2) == 0' /etc/shadow
```

Using Bash

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -f  # do not expand * 

while IFS=":" read -a user
do 
    [[ -z ${user[1]} ]] && 
    echo "User : ${user[0]} has no password"

done < /etc/shadow
```

**Update 1:**

> Can i output the users or give them a temporary password?

Above Bash Script is already giving output usernames.

you can setup temporary password for user using :

```
echo "username:password" | chpasswd
```

Then you can forcefully tell your uses to change password at first log-in :

```
chage -d 0 username
```

**Update 2:**
Some information to check 2nd filed based on, because OP mention that second filed is blank but this is not possible unless it's edited by hand.

`/etc/passwd` file 2nd field denote `x` means password is in `/etc/shadow` file, and in

`/etc/shadow` 2nd field has :

- `!{ecrypted passwd}` == user is locked
- `*` or `!`  == `*` is mostly for system/daemon account. the user will not be able to use a unix password to log in (but the user may log in the system by other means).

Comment: Or, in the absence of root access, you can check `$2` in `/etc/passwd`.

Comment: How do i use this in a script? Can i output the users or give them a temporary password?  Thanks for your help

Comment: @BlueFox Please once check updated answer and let me know if you have any doubts